# Milkdown Editor get latest change

Tags: javascript, typescript, markdown, prose-mirror

Iam trying to make an CollabEditor myself, now i want to get the changes from the editor.
But iam only able to get the full markdown or json.

If the user types "Hello" i want to get:

//string is the add string, start is the index where it got added

1. change: {string:'H', start:0}
2. change: {string:'e', start:1}
3. change: {string:'l', start:2}
4. change: {string:'l', start:3}
5. change: {string:'o', start:4}

It is possible that the user pastes the string then it should output:

1. change: {string:'Hello', start:0}

On delete it should output:

//from delet from, to index

1. change: {from:0, to:4}

Maybe someone knows how this could work with the MilkdownEditor

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I found an other solution, i found YJS to make my Editor synced with all other users